# Geolocation API and GIS Data

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, gis

I am working to develop a web app that can utilize a GNSS receiver connected to a smart device to plot points of interest and display them on a map. I am trying to capture the enhanced location data that is being provided via the GNSS receiver. Connecting a GNSS receiver to an android phone or tablet, you have to enable mock locations on the device. The web app works while the GNSS unit is not connected, but once it connects, Chrome is unable to load any location at all, using either getcurrentposition() or watchposition(). The team I am working with thinks the browser might not recognize the units the GPS device is measuring (degrees minutes seconds as opposed to decimal degrees), but I am not so sure this is the case. The Google maps app works while a device is connected to the GPS unit, but maps.google.com does not, which makes me think this is a browser issue. I've also found other apps from the app store that are able to take readings from the device's mock locations. Not being able to use the improved accuracy of the GNSS unit limits the app to the GPS information the phone/tablet provides. Any thoughts about how I could make this work?

Comment: This is probably due to limitations on what the browser can access - you don't really have access to hardware via the browser, for security reasons. Hence, this will probably only work with a proper app. Not 100% sure, but I would guess that to be the case, if you can't get any information off the device. You could probably write a JAVA-app that can access the device, and work on a webpage, but it will demand the user to allow it, and will bring a whole new lot of security issues.